# Discrepancies between pasting from system clipboard ("+ register) vs nvim clipboard

Tags: neovim

When pasting using `p` in nvim, I'm encountering discrepancies:

a) when I yank line using `yy` in nvim and want to paste it, nvim creates a new line below the cursor and pastes that yanked line there

b) when I copy something from the internet and want to use paste it using `"+p`, nvim pastes it exact at the cursor position instead of creating new line and pasting it there (to get the same result as if i was pasting the text yanked from vim, I need to use `"+]p`)

Now when I set `nvim.opt.clipboard "unnamedplus"` and I'm using `"+` register to copy text from nvim into the system clipboard, the discrepancy remains:

a) when I yank from nvim and paste with `p`, it creates a new line below the cursor and pastes that yanked line there (the same as if `nvim.opt.clipboard` option was not set)

b) when I copy from the internet and paste with `p` (no longer using `"+p)`, it still pastes at the cursor position instead of creating a new line below and pasting it there

I've searched `:h` sections but I don't see it being mentioned. Is there a way to fix it so that nvim always creates a new line below and pastes the text there, no matter if I yanked it in nvim or copied from internet? Or make a keybind to handle both scenarios, pasting at the cursor position with `ctrl + p` and pasting below with `p`, no matter if it has been yanked from vim or copied from the internet?

Answer (score 1):

`yy` copies text **linewise**. It seems that when pasting linewise text, neovim first create a newline and then paste text there, see [this source code](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/b4da4783f98837efb7192a3e5a40dd491aeb1491/src/nvim/ops.c#L2941C1-L2943C6). Texts copied from the internet might be considered **charwise** and no newline is created.

If you want to copy a line inside neovim and then paste it back to neovim without the newline, try `0y$` when copying. As `:h charwise` says, motions that move within a line (like `0` and `$`) is taken as charwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the registers making them linewise, characterewise or blockwise. Here is an example function of mine:

```lua
-- this helps us paste a line from the clipboard that
-- has a new line
M.linewise_clipboard = function()
  vim.cmd("call setreg('+', @+, 'l')")
  print('set + reg: linewise!')
end
```

I also have some neovim keymaps to deal with line text-objects

```lua
-- line text-objects
-- https://vimrcfu.com/snippet/269
vim.keymap.set(
  'o',
  'al',
  [[v:count==0 ? ":<c-u>normal! 0V$h<cr>" : ":<c-u>normal! V" . (v:count) . "jk<cr>" ]],
  {
    expr = true,
    desc = mapfile .. 'Operstor pending a line',
  }
)

vim.keymap.set(
  'v',
  'al',
  [[v:count==0 ? ":<c-u>normal! 0V$h<cr>" : ":<c-u>normal! V" . (v:count) . "jk<cr>" ]],
  {
    expr = true,
    desc = mapfile .. 'Visual a line',
  }
)

vim.keymap.set(
  'o',
  'il',
  [[v:count==0 ? ":<c-u>normal! ^vg_<cr>" : ":<c-u>normal! ^v" . (v:count) . "jkg_<cr>"]],
  {
    expr = true,
    desc = mapfile .. 'Operstor pending inner line',
  }
)

vim.keymap.set(
  'v',
  'il',
  [[v:count==0 ? ":<c-u>normal! ^vg_<cr>" : ":<c-u>normal! ^v" . (v:count) . "jkg_<cr>"]],
  {
    expr = true,
    desc = mapfile .. 'Visual inner line',
  }
)
```

If I want to copy a line with no enter I do: `yil`

By the way: The mapfile is just an icon I put in my mappings description to help me debug them:

```lua
local mapfile = " "
```